# how to print a vowpal wabbit regression model in contextual bandits setting

Tags: python, vowpalwabbit

I am using vowpal wabbit for contextual bandit problem, in python.
Vowpal wabbit has a prediction model that uses the doubly robust method to build a regression model to predict the cost for different actions. This model is thenused by the exploration strategy to output predictions.

Is there a way to print (in python) what the predicted regression model is and what the variables, coefficients are. I cannot find a way to print the model like a typical regression model summary (containing the variable, coefficients, std errors, p values etc.)

Comment: @arielf Can you please throw some light on this, in case you are aware of

Comment: @jackgerrits Can you please throw some light on this, in case you are aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you initialize vw in python, you could use the `--invert_hash <file_name>` command and that will print a readable version of the model to the file provided (see [here](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments) for details).

If you are using vw 9.1.0 you can also use this new experimental feature that exports the model in a json format (see release notes [here](https://vowpalwabbit.org/blog/vowpalwabbit-9.1.0.html), check for "Export model weights and readable feature names as JSON")

If you are building from source, the above experimental api has been recently exposed via the python interface (see [here](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/pull/3858))

Comment: A separate question, do you know if we can make vowpal wabbit predictions inbatch, instead of making predictions on one observation each time

Comment: Also is there a way to train the vowpal wabbit model vw.learn on more the 1 exmaple at a time like train in batches/whole dataset instead of on a single example.